# Tensorflow aggregation_method for optimizers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I could not find documentation regarding the aggregation method in tensorflow optimizer

I have the following line of code

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=batch, aggregation_method = tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_TREE)
```

However, this property can be changed to be

```
tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N
```

Does anyone know what does it do? (I just know that when I used the default with an LSTM it did not have enough memory to run)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `AggregationMethod`, `EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N` is to `ADD_N` (`DEFAULT`) as [accumulate_n](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/accumulate_n) is to [add_n](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_n). `add_n` waits for all of its arguments to be available before doing any summation, while `accumulate_n` sums as soon as its inputs are available. This may save memory, but has some picky shape information limitations because its current implementation requires creating a temporary variable.

There is a bit of documentation [in the comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L814):

```
      # The benefit of using AccumulateN is that its inputs can be combined
      # in any order and this can allow the expression to be evaluated with
      # a smaller memory footprint.  When used with gpu_allocator_retry,
      # it is possible to compute a sum of terms which are much larger than
      # total GPU memory.
      # AccumulateN can currently only be used if we know the shape for
      # an accumulator variable.  If this is not known, or if we only have
      # 2 grads then we fall through to the "tree" case below.
```

Comment: Thanks ! This helped me understand it a bit better. one more question though: when I use the default, the GPU is out of memory, but when I use `EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N` it only uses half of my GPU memory, why is that? I expected it to fill it all up.

Comment: Are you measuring this with nvidia-smi or with a timeline? Is there anything else using GPU memory? For a fixed graph, memory usage should be relatively constant (there is some nondeterminism due to op scheduling); typically people adjust their batch size to fill up GPU memory (for image models at least). TensorFlow does not automatically use more memory just because it's available (aside from some "allowed to fail" allocations which you'll get warnings about).

Comment: Im measuring using nvidia-smi. yes. Well, its unexpected. I have an LSTM which caused it to run out of resources and then when using the accumulate_n its using less than maximum. I think that before it tried to do all of the LSTM time steps at once and now it dows it one at a time (but why not 2 or 3 at a time... ? ) 
thank you for your answers.

Comment: TensorFlow's memory usage in nvidia-smi is just a loose upper bound on the amount of memory TensorFlow is actually using, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. Usually it allocates all available GPU memory to start with (configurable), so a lower reported memory usage in nvidia-smi may just mean something else is blocking it from making the full allocation. Probably `accumulate_n` is saving just enough memory to avoid allocation errors (because intermediate Tensors so longer need to wait around). It won't change the number of steps being executed.